# How do I conduct an if condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
          hours
0          12
1          19
2          22
3          12
4           8
5          24
6          19
7          22 
8          4
9          26
```

the above is my data, and i have created my DataFrame df as well.
Im trying to create a condition where if the values are >= 24 they should essentially print 0, if not to print the value as it is.
ive tried df.loc but it doesnt seem to work, it just prints the values again as it is ignoring the condition.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.where`:

```py
df["hours"] = np.where(df["hours"] >= 24, 0, df["hours"])
df
```

##### Output

|  | hours |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 12 |
| 1 | 19 |
| 2 | 22 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 4 | 8 |
| 5 | 16 |
| 6 | 0 |
| 7 | 20 |
| 8 | 4 |
| 9 | 0 |

Answer (score 1):

Mask the `hours` columns:

```
df['hours'][df['hours']>=24] = 0
```